# Getting error on limit in MySQL

Tags: mysql

> You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 0, 30'

I get this error when I try to use this code :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS prodaja;

CREATE TABLE prodaja ( id SERIAL, id_stvari BIGINT, id_kupca BIGINT, kvantitet INT, cijena DECIMAL(9,2), podmireno INT );
INSERT INTO prodaja (id_stvari, id_kupca, kvantitet, cijena, podmireno) VALUES (1, 3, 5, 19.95, 0);
INSERT INTO prodaja (id_stvari, id_kupca, kvantitet, cijena, podmireno) VALUES (2, 2, 3, 14.95, 1);
INSERT INTO prodaja (id_stvari, id_kupca, kvantitet, cijena, podmireno) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 29.95, 0);
SELECT * FROM prodaja;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updateprodaja BEFORE UPDATE ON prodaja
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF ( SELECT podmireno FROM prodaja WHERE id = NEW.id ) > 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Ne mogu azurirati red imena podmireno u tablici prodaja';
        END IF;
    END
//
DELIMITER ;

START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE prodaja SET kvantitet = kvantitet + 9 WHERE id = 1;
COMMIT;
```

I really don't know where the problem is... Can someone help me out?

Comment: The error is not from the code you show. Is other code triggered from the code you run?

Comment: The error message does not match with the given code. Its getting generated from a select statement with limit.

Comment: Could you give me more info? I'm using the latest XAMPP. I tried removing the SELECT right after the inserts, but I still get those errors. Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a UI that automatically tacks on `LIMIT 30` to whatever you enter?  What version of what UI?  Also, what version of MySQL?

Solution:  Upgrade the UI.